# How to get a link for BLOB download on interactive report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have got this query:

```
select MATERIAL_NAME,
       FILENAME,
       MIME_TYPE,
       DOC_SIZE,
       CONTENT
from materials;
```

Here the `CONTENT` column is of type `BLOB`. I can't get it to display a download link when I set its type to "Download BLOB", and its attributes etc.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tries to improve the language and the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't select the column itself, but its *size*, i.e.

```
select 
  MATERIAL_NAME,
  FILENAME,
  MIME_TYPE,
  DOC_SIZE,
  -- No: CONTENT
  -- Yes:
  dbms_lob.getlength(content) content
from materials;
```

**[EDIT: some more info]**

Navigate to "content" column's properties and set the following properties (that's the minimum set you have to fill; if you know other values, fill them as well):

- type: download BLOB
- BLOB attributes:

  - table name: materials
  - BLOB column: content
  - primary key column 1: I don't know; set it to table's primary key column

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I typed everything as above and also changed my CONTENT column's type to download BLOB, as well as its attributes, but my query now returns the error "ORA-01403: no data found" Do you have any clue as to how I can solve this? Before changing CONTENT column's type, it query back my file's size.

Comment: I've added some more info; have a look, please.

Comment: This is exactly what I did and this error is still showing. :(

Comment: Did you include the primary key column into the SELECT clause? If not, do it. You don't have to display it, though (set it to be "hidden").