# Oracle Apex Classic Report Download gets incorrect File Type

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm following the steps described on this entry:

[How to get a link for BLOB download on interactive report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408739/how-to-get-a-link-for-blob-download-on-interactive-report)

Using:

```
Create table my_table (id  NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
file_blob,
FILE_MIMETYPE,
FILE_CHARSET,
file_size)
```

I'm using a Form (and its automatic process) to insert the files into it.
That part works perfectly.
But, when I create my report to download it, I get a 'file type' instead of the actual file type I uploaded. E.g.:

[image]

Any idea why?

thanks

Comment: Did you try adding the extension name (.pdf) to the downloaded file. If it opens correctly with the correct extension in the file name, change the filename of the downloaded files by concatenating file type at the end.

Comment: Thank you @cengizsevimli that works, but file types will be different. Also, users are not going to know how to do this I'm 99% sure.
Any idea how to fix? thanks!

Comment: when uploading the file to the DB, mime type column shoul be used correctly so you store the file type and when downloading the file, use that column value.

Comment: Have a look at the sample upload/download app, it has a working example of upload/download functionality and it also has an interactive report. The "Download BLOB" column type has filename as attribute, what did you put in that ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your BLOB column, set type to Download BLOB and set column attributes as on image below.

[image]